# Load images synchronusly in constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, async-await

I'm making a 2D programming game for my school. In this game you control robots and do tasks with them. The robots can face in 4 directions, and each of them has its source image. When the game loads the images are loaded in the Robot() constructor.

```js
constructor(name, x, y, res, facing) { // res - the paths of the images (strings)
    super(x, y, facing);
    this.name = name;
    this.res = res ? res.map(s => { // I want the loaded Image objects
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = s;
        return img;
    }) : null;
}
```

The problem with this is that the images load after the initial render and the game only renders if it's updated, so the robots are invisible until screen resize or movement. I can't use `Promise.all()` in the constructor. Because this is a game for beginner programmers I don't want to use static workarounds as that would make the adding of new robots more complicated. Also I don't want to call drawing in the constructor because robots can be added runtime and sometimes a lot of them, so rendering after every call would be really inefficient.

This is an example program that a student would write in a separate file:

```js
let r = map.robot; // the robot is pre-loaded with the map
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        r.Move();
    r.Turn_right();
}
```

Comment: Using a static method is not a workaround, it is the proper solution. I would argue that this is actually easier to understand for beginner programmers than a constructor that does weird things - especially if they will be using `async`/`await` already.

Comment: You should not do a complete render after each image is loaded, you just should trigger an asynchronous render. There's no problem with having lots of calls that all just schedule the same rendering.

Comment: If your goal is to make the `Robot` class as simple as possible, and even have your pupils work with its code, you should consider removing the `draw` method entirely and just have a service that takes all robots on the board and knows how to draw them - including loading their assets and re-rendering the board when all asset loading is done.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that the users (of course can) but most likely will not see the Robot class just use its methods, I'll edit in an example task program.

Comment: Especially if the robot instance comes pre-loaded with the map and is not even created by the students, there is nothing that should stop you from writing `map.robot = await Robot.createWithImage(); evaluateProgram(map, 'separate_file.js')`?